Are these called roller shutters in the US and Canada or not?
Or are they called security blinds/shutters? I mean the covers covering the windows and the entrances of those stores in a mall.



Have you tried typing roller shutters USA into a search engine such as Google?

In the US we tend not to put those shutters on residential windows. They're mainly used by commercial establishments. If I were searching for a vendor online, I'd search with "security shutters" or "security blinds".  (Having just tried it, I see also "Rolling Security Shutters" and "Rollup Security Shutters")

"Rollup" as an adjective is an interesting formation from the phrasal verb.

There's a range of phrases like "security rolling shutters", "metal shutters", "rolling security shutters", "commercial roll up shutters", etc (and "home security shutters" for the home version) but there doesn't seem to be a strongly preferred option. Why not look at some company websites and see what you like? You may or may not want to distinguish storm shutters and other types of shutters, particular materials, particular construction, etc.

But which one is more natural then??

I usually call them a "roll gate", but this may be very local to New York City.  For example, here's a company called "Rolling Gates NYC".

The roller is probably on the inside of the window but the term is: Roll-up window. Also, roll-up shutters. You have to use the term: Roll-up x.

Can you please give me a yes or no answer already instead of writing unrelated stuff here???!!! Are those roller shutters or not??! Is it that hard to read??! Can you even read??!

No, they are roll-up shutters like roll-up garage, warehouse or shop doors and windows. Rollers are for painting walls or for your hair or for a conveyor belt. Yeah?

Things can have lots of different names, and different names can include different groups of things.
In general:

Any kind of blind or shutter that rolls up can be called a "roller blind" (or shutter)
A blind is something designed primarily  to either keep sunlight out or prevent people looking in. They are generally  inside a window or door.
A shutter is something primarily designed to protect a window, door or opening - from weather, people or something else - or to prevent entry. They are usually outside the window or door.
Any shutter whose main purpose is to protect from deliberate damage by people, or to prevent entry, would be called a security shutter.
A shutter that is the only means of closing an entryway can also be called a door. If it's job is security then it's a security door. If it rolls up then it's a roller door.


Thank you so much for the very helpful answer! :-)

As noted in the comments, these are not common on residential properties in the US, so there isn't a specific colloquial name for them. Like the commenters, I would describe the commercial use as "rolling security shutter" or even "roll-up security gate." However, that doesn't tell you much, since I (like most Americans, I suspect, had never considered the name of this item until you asked).
I would default to whatever name they are being sold under as the "correct" name to discuss them in that context.

roll up blinds and windows shades are common. Also, in industrial uses, roll-up doors and windows are common.
